# Run Flutter Code in Background at Specific DateTime

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a reminder app, which should remind the user to complete a specific task at a given DateTime. In order to accomplish the same, the approach that I have followed is to use [android_alarm_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager) and then dispatch a function every few minutes, to see if the stored DateTime is equal to/past the current DateTime, but I believe there ought to be a better approach.

How can I execute the Flutter code in background at a specific DateTime?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch

Comment: Check this page. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes